# Where can I find Gunmar in the Dawnguard quest "A New Order?"

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

In the Dawnguard quest *A New Order*, Sorine had a quest marker but Gunmar does not; I can't find him. How can I get access to the Vale and get Auriel's Bow without doing the quest? Could someone give me an idea as to where I can find him?

I'm playing Skyrim - Legendary Edition on the Xbox 360.

Answer (score 3):

As you're playing the Legendary Edition you have all of the DLC, including Dragonborn. As such, you should be able to find Gunmar in one of the following locations:

In the Skyrim overworld:

- Fallowstone Cave
- Brood Cavern
- Crystaldrift Cave
- Bonechill Passage
- Clearspring Tarn
- Cronvangr Cave
- Honeystrand Cave
- Pinepeak Cavern

Or in the Solstheim overworld:

- Northshore Landing
- Horker Island

([source: TES Wiki's Gunmar page](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Gunmar#Interactions))

If you can't find a map marker for him in the Skyrim overworld, he's probably at one of the two locations in Solstheim.

Answer (score -2):

I found him at Gyldenhul Barrow in Solstheim.